# Contact sensing between a rotating disc and a metal probe

Tags: stm32, adc, ground, proximity-sensor

So I'm trying to retrofit an existing PCB to be used for contact sensing.

Apparatus:
There is a disc rotating at about 9600 rpm. The disc is made out of metal with a coating of diamond dust on top - and is grounded via a 100 Ohm Carbon contacts.
The probe is mounted on a stepper motor which slowly goes down and touches the disc.

The PCB is built on STM32F4 controller family. The Pin can be used as normal GPIO, GPIO Interrupt, and ADC.

I'm using a Falling Edge interrupt with 2nd order Hardware LowPass filter to get rid of noise.

Following the the circuit.

```
     3v3                                 | 
      |                                  |
Pin ----1K-----1K-----Probe    ------>   | DISC---100Ohm---GND
            |      |                     | 9600 RPM
          100nF  100nF                   |    
            |      |
           GND    GND
```

Problem:
Since the probe actually touches a very fast moving disc, the probe gets damaged just a bit every time. I want to avoid that, but at the same time don't want to have false contact. (It does work consistently, but the probe gets damaged bit by bit.)

Without the Low Pass Filter - the diamond dust triggers a false sensing.

I tried doing this with fast ADC sampling and it stopped the probe damage, but it gave very unreliable results (A lot of false sensing issues).
So how can I improve on this issue with the existing setup that I have? Is there some way I can use DSP with ADC samples to get an accurate reading?

Comment: Perhaps you can do non-contact sensing (e.g. capacitive or inductive) and subtract the small difference. Inductive would be more suitable for detecting the metal position, capacitive could be made to respond to the diamond, which has a dielectric constant of 5.7.

Comment: Could you redirect me to some examples please?

Comment: what are you trying to determine with the sensor?

Comment: The probe is connected to the diamond. Once the probe makes contact to the plate, a motor would pull the diamond back.
Essentially it is a diamond polishing machine. The probe will be set to a specific angle at which the diamond is supposed to be cut.